# Java and database Connection. Which connection class is better and why?

Tags: java, database, oracle, design-patterns, jdbc

I am using java and some database(`oracle/sql`) to store some information. So I decided to create a **fixed** class which will handle my connection and I shall return a **con** object at the end so I can use it in another classes.

The main thing I have this classes is to be able to establish a connection to database from another class.

Please tell me which one is better and why and if it can be improved.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectDB {

    private static ConnectDB con = new ConnectDB();

    private ConnectDB() {
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection createCon() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","yy","yy");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection to db could not be done");
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public static Connection getConexiune() {
        return con.createCon();
    }
}
```

or i can use this class

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConectDB {
    static   Connection con;

    public static Connection getConexiune() {
        return con;
    }  

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        try{
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
           con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","yy","yy");
           System.out.println("cONNECTED");            
           con.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }   
}
```

which one is better and why?

Does first example use Singleton design pattern?

Comment: good article with code from java site https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-918906

Comment: Questions about how to improve your (working) code can be asked on the http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ site.

Comment: Why don't you use a `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation? That is what they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't like none of them, I think first is less worse than second. First is a kind of Singleton, but it exposes a public method `createCon` that I  think it must be protected or private.

Second one only works after call main method and it can only serve one connection. I don't like it.

Why don't you think about using connection pooling?

### EDIT

Considering your comment, if you want to use a Singleton connection manager, I will use something like that:

```
public class ConnectDB {
    private static ConnectDB instance = null;

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            //TODO manage exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static ConnectDB getInstance(){
        if(null == instance) 
            instance = new ConnectDB();

        return instance;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;

        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","yy","yy");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            //TODO manage exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return connection;      
    }
}
```

Of course, I will create parameters (*encapsulated with getter/setter*) for:

- driver
- host
- port
- dbname
- schema
- user
- password

This way your `getConnection()` method won't have wired values.

Comment: I am not that good ad connection pooling. Isn`t there a way to improve my code? What shall i do?

Answer (score 0):

One connection per application is not good idea.

1. Have a Fixed pool of connections and manage the pool. On releasing the connection, instead of closing the connection, return to the pool
2. You can write your own connection pool Or implement Oracle UCP pool. Have a look at [UCP documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/connect.htm)
3. A house keeping mechanisms required to physically close bad connections ( Timed out connections or broken connections)